# Lambda Layer || Python Runtime 3.11 || Pyodbc-Lib

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc, aws-lambda-layers, python-3.11

Can you please assist me adding the python pyodbc layer for 3.11 python runtime version? Earlier, i had the pyodbc layer for 3.7 which i exported from https://github.com/kuharan/Lambda-Layers?source=post_page-----e7667d371cc5-------------------------------- Now, 3.7 runtime is about to deprecate , i need to switch it to 3.11 latest version.

.I have tried many ways to add but got multiple errors.
i) I used updated pyodbc .whl file and made zip out of it and uploded to aws-layer. but says 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyodbc'

ii) Unable to import module 'app': libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Something like this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out today. For a pyodbc lambda layer that works with the newest Python runtime 3.11, you must place your config files inside of the python folder when creating the zip. Here is a link to my github where I put the .zip file for the pyodbc python 3.11 layer. It has the MSSQL ODBC 17 driver. I could not get it to work with 18 because the sql server I was trying to query was version 12, which I don't think accepts anything newer than 17.

https://github.com/andersonguse/lambda-layers/blob/master/pyodbc311.zip

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!